# MongoDB aggregate $lookup on _id field from String to ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nestjs

I have 2 collections.

## Vouchers

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("584aac38686860d502929b8b"),
  "restaurantId":ObjectId("584aac38686860d502929b8b"),
}
```

## Restaurants

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("584aac38686860d502929b8b"),
  "phoneNumber:1111111111,
  "description:"this is testing description"
}
```

I want to join this collection based on the restaurantId

`(from vouchers   collection) - _id ( in restaurants collection)`.

I want to `populate/fetch` the restaurant document matching the `objectId` present in vouchers collection how to get the desired result my code given below.

```
return this.voucherRedeemModel.aggregate([
{
   $lookup: {
             from: Restaurant.name,
             let: { restaurantId: '$restaurantId' },
   pipeline: [
                {
           $match: {
              $expr: {
                   $eq: [
                       '$_id',
                         {
                          $toObjectId: '$$restaurantId',
                         },
                        ],
                      },
                    },
                  },
               ],
   as: 'restaurants',
           },
       },
]);
```

But it's not working.

## The output I am getting:

```
{
   "_id": "6409660b61e93b69f99782fa",
   "restaurantId": "64082da2a264b35fa2a3e9cf",
   "voucherId": "64087b09b775a52c835d91a4",
   "createdAt": "2023-03-09T04:52:27.370Z",
   "updatedAt": "2023-03-09T04:52:27.370Z",
   "__v": 0,
   "restaurants": []
},
```

Comment: What is the value of `Restaurant.name`?

Comment: 'restaurant' the name of the collection